# In Quarkus/RESTEasy, how do I show helpful error messages for malformed query parameters?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, quarkus

I have a REST endpoint that looks like this:

```
@Path("/api/v1/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UsersResource {
  @GET
  public Uni<ListUsersResponse> list(@BeanParam @Valid ListUsersRequest req) {
    ...
  }
}
  
...

public class ListUsersRequest {
  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  @QueryParam("status_in")
  List<UserStatus> statusIn;
}

...

public enum UserStatus {
  All,
  Creating,
  Deleting,
  ...
}
```

When I make an API call like this:

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users?status_in=invalid_status

Quarkus/RESTEasy will return a 404, and nothing will even show up in the server logs, because it is a 404, because it is a "client error".

If I enable debug logging, the error looks like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.myproject.UserStatus.something
```

I dislike this behaviour, because:

1. A 404 implies "not found", which makes users think that the path they used doesn't exist at all, which is confusing.
2. It's difficult for both users and developers to figure out what went wrong, as there are no error messages in the response or in the server logs without DEBUG enabled.

Apparently, this is on purpose, because it conforms to [some spec](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4976):

> 3.2 Fields and Bean Properties
>
> if the field or property is annotated with @MatrixParam, @QueryParam or @PathParam then an implementation MUST generate an instance of NotFoundException (404 status) that wraps the thrown exception and no entity

So my question is, how can I modify this to actually give helpful error messages and status code?

Comment: You can add a static fromString(string) method to the enum and throw a WebApplicationException with the Response you want.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a variety of exception handlers for just this reason.  For example, I want to check if an incoming JSON body is malformed.  For that I did:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

/**
 * Maps a ReaderException to a response.  A ReaderException is most often thrown
 * when we get a bad JSON packet.
 *
 */
@Provider
public class ReaderExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ReaderException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ReaderException exception) {

        if( exception.getCause() instanceof JsonParseException ||
                exception.getCause() instanceof JsonMappingException ) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .entity("error parsing json body - " + exception.getMessage())
                    .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                    .build();
        }

        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(exception.getMessage())
                .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .build();
    }
}
```

In your case you should be able to create an `ExceptionMapper` for `IllegalArgumentException` and do what you'd like.  I am running this in both Wildfly and Quarkus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may not know the particular Exception ahead of time - in this case it is an IllegalArgumentException, but what if it's a NPE in the future, etc? How did you know to use ReaderException?

Comment: For me I was trying to catch a specific issue - in this case a malformed JSON body.  It was the exception that I was seeing in the in the logs and I wanted a better error message.  Unfortunately, to your point, it's not a great overall solution as it is rather specific.  I've not tried having something like `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` but that seems to be what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `ParamConverter` for generic enum types.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class EnumParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {
    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(final Class<T> rawType, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (!rawType.isEnum()) {
            return null;
        }
        final Enum<?>[] constants = (Enum<?>[]) rawType.getEnumConstants();
        return new ParamConverter<T>() {
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public T fromString(final String value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
                    return null;
                }
                for (Enum<?> e : constants) {
                    if (e.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                        return (T) e;
                    }
                }
                // No match, check toString()
                for (Enum<?> e : constants) {
                    if (e.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                        return (T) e;
                    }
                }
                throw new WebApplicationException(Response.serverError().entity(String.format("Failed to find constant '%s'", value)).build());
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(final T value) {
                return value != null ? value.toString() : null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question for which I gave an answer. Basically I suggested use of `ResponseEntity` class as a return value or creating Exception handler marked as `@ControllerAdvice`. Please look at the answer here: [How to add message to response with exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833072/how-to-add-message-to-response-with-exception/70833247#70833247)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by QueryParamInjector. If, while mapping query params, it catches any exception, that is not inherited from `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException` it will wrap the exception into `NotFoundException`. (see `StringParameterInjector#extractValue(String)` and `QueryParamInjector#throwProcessingException(String, Throwable)`)

You can bypass this behaviour by throwing exception that extends `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException` instead of `IllegalArgumentException`. In my case I use custom ParamConverter where I wrap cought `RuntimeException`s into `javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException`.

Also, custom `ExceptionMapper` for `BadRequestException` would be useful, cause default one will print stacktrace into response