# How to add message to response with exception

Tags: java, spring, httpresponse

I use next: java11 + spring-boot:2.4.3.

I have next method in controller:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public void update(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody OrderDto orderDto) {
    try {
        myService.update(id, orderDto);
    } catch (OrderMovementException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Well, it works fine for tests or logging, I see status and message.

But my front-end colleague  receive next, where message is empty:

```
{"timestamp":"2022-01-24T11:20:48.726+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/service/api/orders/12345"}
```

what I need to change to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look, https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: @Andre I saw it, and its 5. Solution 4: ResponseStatusException (Spring 5 and Above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method could instead or returning void return class `ResponseEntity`. See an article on how to use it: [Using Spring ResponseEntity to Manipulate the HTTP Response](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity). Another way to provide detailed error message is to write a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. See some info on that (and other stuff) here: [Building REST services with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/)